# Laravel sense of using the Notifiable trait on a another class than User

Tags: php, notifications, laravel-5.4

I want to notify the user if something happend in a group. For this I want to use the Notification system provided by Laravel. But I'm confused I should use the `Notifiable` on the User Model or on the Group Model?

For example:
A user writes something in a group or uploads an image, then each user in the group should get a Notification that xy has written/uploaded anything. For each kind of Notification I have an own class, like `ImageUpload, UnreadMessage, etc...`.

Currently I'm doing it like:
 1. Get all Members from the group
 2. `Notification::send($groupMembers, new ImageUpload($image));`  or
 3. `Notification::send($groupMembers, new UnreadMessage($message));`

I know that it's possible to use the `Notifiable` argument on other Models as well but I don't get it what's exactly the point if I would use the Notification on an other model like my `Group` model. The Notifications would then be available via `$group->unreadNotifications`. But would it be possible to mark the Notification as read? You wouldn't know if all members in that group have read it, without using a seperate tabl!?
I cannot think about an example where it would make any sense to use it. Could you provide me one?

So am I using it correctly, or....?